# rosrun warning error

Tags: boost, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i  created a simple package for listner.cpp and talker.cpp. i already build my package. when i run "rosrun firstpack talker", it run successfully and print "hello world". when i open new tab and run my listener node it give me error .

chhonkar@chhonkar-pc:~/Desktop/catkin$ rosrun firs[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /home/chhonkar: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/home/chhonkar/.gvfs"
tpack listner
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named listner below /home/chhonkar/Desktop/catkin/src/firstpack

Both node run successfully when i run it alone. but when i run another node, it return error.
my questions are
Q1- " what is this error?"
Q2 - "why my node run alone but when i execute one after another, it fails and return above error"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196290/rosrun-warning-error/) by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see two separate issues here:

1. You have a permissions problem with your ~/.gvfs directory. I suspect you see this warning when you try to tab-complete your package name. I haven't seen this before; you'll probably want to search the Ubuntu forums or just try rebooting.
2. Your environment isn't set up properly in your new terminal. Are you sure you're sourcing the setup.bash for your workspace properly? (Note that with catkin, setting the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH manually is no longer sufficient to tell ROS where your workspace is).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/76896/permission-denied-gvfs/), running these two commands

```
#umount /home/useraccount/.gvfs
#rm -rf .gvfs/
```

will fix the first issue.

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-10-30**:
Problem goes different. this time, nodes are not running. I rebuild the package. and when i use the command "rosrun firstpack talker", it return
chhonkar@chhonkar-pc:~/Desktop/catkin$ rosrun firstpack talker
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/chhonkar/Desktop/catkin/src/first

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-30**:
In the new tab, did you run `'source devel/setup.bash'` in your workspace?

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-10-31**:
i got the solution. what i did, first run roscore, open new tab and execute export path and source path command and run the rosrun firstpack talker. open new tab, and AGAIN execute export and source command and then run rosrun firstpack listener. ........ it works fine.

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-10-31**:
Is there any way to fixed or save ROS_PACKAGE_PATH  and SOurce command , so that i did not required to define ROS_PACKAGE_PATH AND SOURCE again and again.???

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-31**:
You can add them in your `~/.bashrc` file

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-10-31**:
i am just new to ubuntu, can you tell me where i can find it.... and how i can??

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-10-31**:
run    `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-11-04**:
@ROSCMBOT how can i add the path to this file. when i run this command. a horrible file open which is difficult to understand. Please help me.